# python requests to urllib2

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

I have python 2.5 installed and I cannot update it, I need to call an API without requests module but with urllib2 I'm not able to make it working.

below the working code using requests:

```
import requests
import json

login = "x"
password = "x"

headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }

data = {
    'subject' : 'MAIL_001',
    'description' : 'detail'
}

r = requests.post("https://site", auth = (login, password), headers = headers, data = json.dumps(ticket))
```

My test using urllib2 and simplejson:

```
import urllib2
import simplejson
import base64

login = "x"
password = "x"

data = {
'subject' : 'MAIL_001',
'description' : 'detail'
}

request = urllib2.Request("https://site", simplejson.dumps(data))
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (login, password)).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)  
request.add_header("Content-Type", "application/json")
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

I think it's the same code using urllib2 but obviously it is not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong.  I assume you know you have to call `result.read()` for the urllib2 version ...

Comment: What doesn't work about it? What does happen?